# Facing WARN Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false` in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, banner, react-native-reanimated

I am using native-banner-carousel for showing banner images in my react native project. Although it has been implemented successfully and working absolutely fine but I encountered a problem. Every time the image of banner gets changed and the dots underneath the banner moves to the new position I am getting a warning in my console. The warning is:

> WARN  Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`

Then I tried using the the other library which is : @ro4z/react-native-banner-carousel
But problem is still same, I've tried to solve this issue in many ways but failed.

Then I tried using the the other library `@ro4z/react-native-banner-carousel`. I've upgraded the library to the latest version but still problem is same

Comment: Hi Ankur! Welcome to stack overflow. It seems like you're a new user. It doesn't matter whether you use @ro4z/react-native-banner-carousel or react-native-banner-carousel library, you need to add following code snippet in your node_modules\react-native-banner-carousel\out\Carousel file animation: (animate, toValue) => { return react_native_1.Animated.spring(animate, { useNativeDriver: false, // Add this line toValue: toValue, friction: 10, tension: 50, }); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

animation: (animate, toValue) => {
return react_native_1.Animated.spring(animate, {
useNativeDriver: false,
toValue: toValue,
friction: 10,
tension: 50,
});
}